# Spanning Set Definition

Tags: linear-algebra

The definition I have been giving of a spanning set is the following;

If $V = span(S)$, then $S$is called a spanning set for $V$ and we
say $V$ is spanned by $S$.

My confusion here is what if all the vectors in $V$ can be written as linear combinations of the ones in $S$, but there are some linear combinations of the elements in $S$ that are not in $V$, is it still a spanning set, because it still spans the whole space so it seems like it'd be true but the definition implies otherwise.

Comment: $S$ is a subset of $V$ so all linear combinations of vectors in $S$ are in $V$.

Answer (score 1):

If all the vectors in $V$ can be written as a linear combination of the ones in $S$ then $S$ spans $V$. Your concern about there being some linear combinations of elements in $S$ that are not in $V$ is trivial. Since each element of $S$ is an element of $V$ and $V$ is a vector space, all linear combinations of elements in $S$ will be elements of $V$. This is because of the axioms of a vector space, namely that it is closed under addition and scalar multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

It would not be called a spanning set for $V$ (even though it spans more than $V$). You would only be able to say that $V$ is a subspace of $span(S)$.

Answer (score 0):

Because the definition has a precondition. S should be a subset of V .
So any linear conbination of elements in S must belong to V